# Not able to run WCF default Class library project from a specific path

Tags: c#, wcf

When creating a WCF class library project it runs fine if I run that project from my desktop but it does not run if I run it from a different path!!!

I created 30 sec video that demonstrates this in action:

### http://youtu.be/5dLRQhlhe9A

In the video I basically create a project, run it, then show how I get an error. I close visual studio then move that project that to a different path run it and it works because it is on a different path.

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://********:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex If
>   this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI:
>   http://********:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://********:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex'.
>   `Receivera:InternalServiceFault`The server was unable to process the request due to
>   an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn
>   on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug>
>   configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception
>   information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://********:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex
>   There was an error downloading
>   'http://********:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

note:
 I replaced ******** with localhost, StackOverflow did not let me place links with 127.0.0.1 for security reasons.

Comment: So that error message lists several things for you to try to track this down. There's a very good chance that if you follow the suggestions there, you'll solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

1. Access your bad-place metadata by url from browser

I mean, try to open in your browser url
'http://**:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AccService/Service1/mex'

and be sure you can see the wsdl.

If not - this will point your way to go with additional tests.

1. Change behavior to expose metadata in certain location, you can access without problem.

Something like `<serviceMetadata . . . httpGetUrl=`"**your verified metadata url**" . . .
(see also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) post):

```
<serviceMetadata 
    externalMetadataLocation="String"
    httpGetBinding=”String”    httpGetBindingConfiguration=”String”
    httpGetEnabled="Boolean" 
    httpGetUrl="String"
    httpsGetBinding=”String”    httpsGetBindingConfiguration=”String”
    httpsGetEnabled="Boolean" 
    httpsGetUrl="String"
    policyVersion="Policy12/Policy15"/>
```